# First Item not being added to the session

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have a pretty basic shopping cart. The problem is that except for the first item in the list all other items are working fine. 
The way it works:

The products list coming from db have a button on each which is attached to a JS function which 
then, using the "load" jquery function it connects to a php script that adds the product to the session['basket']. I put an alert in the JS function and the first item (the one with the problem) looks fine. Also, put an echo " session exists" if a session is created in the php page. The first Icon does create a session, but shows no data like product name, etc.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Products List:

```
<?php require_once('inc.php');

  if ($prod->data != "") {
    foreach ($prod->data as $p) {

         if ($p['qty'] > 0) { ?>
            <ul style="text-align: left">
                <li><strong>Nome: </strong><?php echo $p['name']; ?> </li>
                <li><strong>Categoria: </strong><?php echo($p['category']); ?>      </li>
                <li><strong>Preço: </strong>&pound;<?php printf("%.2f", $p['priceUnit']); ?> </li>
                <li><strong>Stock: </strong><?php echo($p['qty']); ?> </li>
                <select id="<?php echo "prod_" . $p['id'] . "qty"; ?>" name="prodqty">
                    <?php
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= $p['qty']; $i++) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select> <br /><br />
            </li>
            <li><button class="button" onclick="addItem('<?php echo $p['id']; ?>', '<?php echo $p['name']; ?>', '<?php echo $p['category']; ?>',
                            '<?php echo $p['priceUnit']; ?>', '<?php echo "#prod_" . $p['id'] . "qty"; ?>');">Adicionar</button>
            </li>
            </ul>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
     <div id="items">

        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['basket'])) {
                  echo "SESSION EXISTS";
                 $total = "";
                  foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $item){ ?>
                      <table>
                          <tr>
                              <td><?php echo $item['name'];?></td>
                              <td>&pound;<?php echo $item['price'];?></td>
                              <td> <?php echo $item['qty'];?></td>
                              <td><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?id=<?php echo $item['id'];?>&amp; action=remove">Eliminar</a></td>
                          <tr>
                      </table>

                         <?php $total+= $item['subtotal'];?>

                      <?php  } ?>
                    <h3> Total a pagar: <span style="color:#000000">&pound;<?php printf("%.2f", $total);?></span></h3>

             <?php    }

                 ?>

        </div>
        <p class="output"></p>
```

JS:

```
 function addItem(id,name,cat,price,qty){

    alert('id: '+id+' name: '+name+' cat: '+cat+ ' price: '+price+' qty: '+$(qty).val());
    var qty2 = $(qty).val();
    var subtotal = price * qty2;
    if($('.output').load('basket.php',{name:name,price:price,cat:cat,id:id,qty2:qty2})){

       window.location.reload();
   }
}
```

PHP SCRIPT basket.php

```
  <?php require_once("inc.php");?>
 <?php


  $_id = CleanData($_POST['id']);
  $_name = CleanData($_POST['name']);
  $_price = CleanData($_POST['price']);
  $_qty = CleanData($_POST['qty2']);
  $_cat = CleanData($_POST['cat']);

  $basket = new ShoppingBasket();
  $basket->Add($_id,$_name, $_cat,$_price, $_qty);

?>
```

SHOPPING BASKET CLASS

```
<?php

class ShoppingBasket{


public function Add($id,$name,$cat,$price,$qty)
{

    //1. Check if the session basket exists
    if(!$_SESSION['basket']){


        $item=array('id'=>$id,
                    'name'=>$name,
                    'cat'=>$cat,
                    'price'=>$price,
                    'qty'=>$qty,
                    'subtotal'=>$qty * $price);           


        //store the first item in the session

        $_SESSION['basket'][$id]=$item;


     //2. Check if the item exists in the basket session

     }  else if ($_SESSION['basket'][$id]) {

         //update this item qty and subtotal

         $_SESSION['basket'][$id]['qty']+=$qty;
         $_SESSION['basket'][$id]['subtotal'] = $_SESSION['basket'][$id]['qty'] * $_SESSION['basket'][$id]['price'];


      //3. Add new Item to existing basket
       }else{
            //group parameters to associative array

        $item=array('id'=>$id,
                    'name'=>$name,
                    'cat'=>$cat,
                    'price'=>$price,
                    'qty'=>$qty,
                    'subtotal'=>$qty * $price);



        //Add new item to existing  basket

        $_SESSION['basket'][$id]=$item;

       }

    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Did you add `session_start()` on the top of the page?

Comment: yes, it's in the inc.php . As i say everything works except the first item in the list, which creates a session but no data is added.

Comment: @lolka_bolka No, there is no sintax error, i'm just having problems with pasting the code in here and the formatting. it seems to be cutting my code.I dont even see the <div id="items"> it cutted. wtf.

Comment: Ok, i saw after you've edited your code.

Comment: will try and edit again for the 3rd time :(

Comment: Do you have this problem in every single case? What if you click the firs item after adding another item?

Comment: @theLibertine yes, it's in all single cases. even thought was a db and field name, like some un-escaped characters that could be messing the script, so i deleted the first product in the list. guess what, the next on the list now the first, is behaving the same :( this is driving me nuts, i have no idea why is doing that.

Comment: I know it's not best practice, but have you tried var_dumping the $_SESSION['basket'] array? Maybe it's just an array index problem. What if you try this `$_SESSION['basket'][count($_SESSION['basket']) + 1]=$item;` instead of `$_SESSION['basket'][$id]=$item;`

Comment: @theLibertine right, I'm dumping and the first item is only  "()" in the array. As for your suggestion, I'm still working around it because it worked for the 1st item but then when I add other items, it just keeps on repeating the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed all the javascript and just used plain php. There must be a problem with the jQuery load() function and G Chrome I had something similar in another project where session would get updated but not always. It worked fine i FF though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine the 1st and 3rd case of your conditions in the add method:

```
public function Add($id, $name, $cat, $price, $qty) {
    //1. Check if the session basket exists or the item exists in basket
    if (!$_SESSION['basket'] || !array_key_exist($id, $_SESSION["basket"])) {
        $item = array('id' => $id,
            'name' => $name,
            'cat' => $cat,
            'price' => $price,
            'qty' => $qty,
            'subtotal' => $qty * $price);
        //store the item in the session
        $_SESSION['basket'][$id] = $item;
    } else {
        //update this item qty and subtotal
        $_SESSION['basket'][$id]['qty']+=$qty;
        $_SESSION['basket'][$id]['subtotal'] = $_SESSION['basket'][$id]['qty'] * $_SESSION['basket'][$id]['price'];

    }
}
```

The other thing. This is really bad:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['basket'])) echo "SESSION EXISTS"; {
```

This means, if `$_SESSION["basket"]` exist, then echo something, and this is the end of your condition. (Anyway, the existing code will produce a syntax error.)

You should add the bracket right after the if:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['basket']))  {
    echo "SESSION EXISTS";
    //.....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried it but I'm still having the same problem. :(

Comment: and i do not see where you include the `inc.php` in your shopping basket class.

Comment: It's not in the class, it's in the page display in the top of page. If it was the problem nothing would work, all sessions work except the first item as i explain in the top question

Comment: yeah that was a mistake while writing that line in here. just edited.

Comment: Right, I'm gonna try and remove the javascript, just using php post vars and session to see if the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are indexing the basket array with the product id coming from the db.

```
$_SESSION['basket'][$id]=$item;
```

This would not work if you do some operation that just loops through the array, like you do:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $item){ 
    //do something
}
```

because you don't have a product with 0 as id. Loops start from zero, maybe that's the issue.
I think maybe you can do something like this, but this is not optimized code, I just would rethink the solution ASAP.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $item){ 
    if($item != array()){
        //do something if the item is not an empty array
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but still having the same problem. :(

Comment: I remove all the javascript, just using php and it works ok. so it must be a javascript/jQuery problem. How reliable is the load() function?